# How can I change the marker?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, marker

A member helped me with a few things about this but I need to change the "Marker" to a small picture I have ..

```
  String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "My location name";
    String latit = "37.925942";
    String longit = "23.938683";
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("geo:<"+latit+">,<"+longit+">?q=<"+latit+">,<"+longit+">("+DESTINATION_LOCATION+")")); //name the label
    startActivity(intent);
```

How can I do that?

---

Edited

```
location.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                userMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.925942, 23.938683))
                .title("You are Here")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.lin)));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You want to change the marker? Means display something other than red bubble structure?

Comment: try this link:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: @Nabin yes, I want to do that.

Comment: @prakash it's a bit confusing, I tried it but it didn't work!

Comment: Please refer to my answer and ask where you don't get it. Good luck

Comment: you have to use google play service for map v2 to achieve this intent will not help you out

Comment: The thing is, I'm not using API key for it, does the marker have anything to do with it?